# installed ubuntu on usb

Tags: reboot

I have supposedly installed ubuntu on a usb stick. But after I completed that, there is no Ubuntu screen to install it.
What did I do wrong? Do I need to reboot after I have burned it onto an usb with rufus download?
I am a baby boomer. Maybe that explains a few things.
sure would appreciate some help.

Comment: Hi Louii.  Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Were you following a tutorial of some sort?  It sounds like you just put the installer on the USB stick and not "installed ubuntu on a usb stick".  As you suspect, the next step involves booting from the USB stick which usually means pressing a function key (like F12 or F6) to tell the BIOS to boot from the stick and not from your ordinary drive.

Comment: BTW, it's not your age, it's the information you're following that we're most interested in. ;-)

Comment: Hi. I pressed F12. A box came up with all kinds of headings, like elements, console, sources, network....I don't think this is what I want. I downloaded Rufus 3.3 and I think I installed Ubuntu from my files after downloading it.

Comment: I was following a tutorial on youtube. I have Bitdefender on my Windows laptop. It scans (in the background) the usb when I plug it in. I would love to get rid of Windows especially with Jan. 14 looming.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include a link to the Youtube video you're following so that we are all on the same page? :-)

Comment: Ah, the need to press a function key is not within Windows.  It's after your machine has rebooted but before Windows starts.  It's probably easier to "Shut Down" completely and then press the power button.  The BIOS is the very first part of starting up, immediately after you press the power button.   If you get to the spinning dots of Windows starting up you've missed the opportunity.  Reboot and try again.

Comment: Secure boot should be turned off, you may need to press F9 rather than F12, or maybe set the USB as first HDD in BIOS, a list of common USB boot problems can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot.